# A good location to save temporary files for a web app?

Tags: lamp

I am developing a gallery-like web app. Users can request to download all photos under a directory as a zip file. I'm going to implement this feature in this way: create the zip file whose filename is unique for each request, save the file in a directory, and send to the user via x-sendfile.

So what's a good location to save those temporary files? A good location means a directory which is cleaned up automatically? Does this kind of directories exist? The app is running on Linux + Apache + PHP.

Answer (score 0):

One approach i could think of is create a temporary directory with directory name same as the unique filename for each request and put files in it. After the operation ends (successfully or with an exception), make sure you delete this directory

Comment: But the problem is, while sending file via x-sendfile, the web app exits before the file completes sending. So the clean up cannot be done in the web app itself.

Comment: Oh, could you do this, store the last unique directory name somewhere and delete the directory and replace it with new unique name in the next transaction?

Comment: I guess it's not that easy to do that since my app allows the same user account login at multiple machines. It's not that easy to determine the previous download has been completed or not. What I'm looking for is something like the /tmp directory which can be cleaned up by the OS automatically. Not sure if it works if I just put those zip files in /tmp.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Apache Ant here? Because there is a Zip class here :

http://www.jajakarta.org/ant/ant-1.6.1/docs/en/manual/api/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Zip.html

And it has a cleanUp() method which does what you are asking.

Comment: looks like a potential solution! I'll look into it.